# Shortening Existing Panel Circuits

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I will either add a subpanel, or relocate the main one. Most of my existing circuits are old (cloth-clad) NM cable, which I have too many projects to replace any time soon. The cable runs are all longer than required for the new panel location.

It appears that I could repurpose the existing main panel as a (large) junction box, and extend the existing circuits to a new panel. However, a cleaner approach (IMO) would be rerouting (and shortening) the old NM (only within the garage roof structure). Is it code-compliant to do this, or would I need to rewire if I don't go for the "junction box" approach?

Comment: Before touching those wires, pick a circuit that you can do without for a while.  Turn off the breaker for it and remove the wires.  If just looking at it funny the insulation breaks, then do not touch any other circuits.  If playing with the wires does not damage them then either choice is good.  You do need an accessible junction box for any splices made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the old panel as a junction box is done quite frequently provided it's in good shape along with a good cover. It will have to remain always accessible.

The use of the old cloth clad is usually not allowed in renovations and would be up to the inspectors since this isn't really a renovation. I would not be rerouting it because it would be very easy to damage the insulation while removing the staples that are probably holding it in place and bending it to the new framing. Any damage would be hard to detect and would surface only after energizing it.

Comment: Good point about damaging the old NM when moving it.

Comment: From more research, I've found that PGE (Northern California) prohibits the reuse of the old panel as a junction box (in my situation). The AHJ (Los Altos, CA) will allow me to reroute the old NM, if it is in good enough condition.

Answer (score 4):

My AHJ allowed me to shorten the old, cloth-covered, NM, and connect it to the new panel. I was pleasantly surprised at the condition of the old wiring - it's from 1952, so 71 years old, but wasn't brittle, just very dirty.

[image: Old NM]

Comment: Good to know it worked out for you. Thanks for the update.